# The meaning of 'attribute A to B' in the context

Tags: meaning

I think '**attribute causes to events**(line5)' should be 'attribute events to causes' although I am rather sure that I misunderstood. Why did the author write that way? Does **attribute** mean 'regard something as being caused by (someone or something)' in this context? The meaning evades me.

> People are innately disposed to look for causes of events, to form
>   explanations and stories. That is one reason storytelling is such a
>   persuasive medium. Stories resonate with our experiences and provide
>   examples of new instances. From our experiences and the stories of
>   others we tend to form generalizations about the way people behave and
>   things work. We **attribute causes to events**, and as long as these
>   cause-­and-­effect pairings make sense, we use them for understanding
>   future events. Yet these causal attributions are often mistaken.
>   Sometimes they implicate the wrong causes, and for some things that
>   happen, there is no single cause. Rather, there is a complex chain of
>   events that all contribute to the result; if any one of the events
>   would not have occurred, the result would be different. But even when
>   there is no single causal act, that doesn’t stop people from assigning
>   one.
>
> > [The Design of Everyday Things: Revised and Expanded Edition](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=I1o4DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&lpg=PT72&dq=We+attribute+causes+to+events,+and+as+long+as+these+cause+and+effect+pairings+make+sense,+we+use+them+for+understanding+future+events.+Yet+these+causal+attributions+are+often+mistaken.&source=bl&ots=6-JVFPDABu&sig=CwTeNO1EVXv1275ob5oU3t9TkAs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjeg4m0jMvdAhVFUbwKHTRxB9EQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20attribute%20causes%20to%20events%2C%20and%20as%20long%20as%20these%20cause%20and%20effect%20pairings%20make%20sense%2C%20we%20use%20them%20for%20understanding%20future%20events.%20Yet%20these%20causal%20attributions%20are%20often%20mistaken.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the author is using attribute to roughly mean **attach**. Therefore, the sentence reads as "We attach causes to events".

'Attribute events to causes' indicates that the causes are already existing, and when the event happens it is attached to a cause.

'Attribute causes to events' indicates that the cause is found retroactively, and may not have existed as a noticeable effect before the event occurred.